# Convert part of the data included in an XML file to a CSV file

Tags: python, xml, csv

I would like to convert an XML file to a CSV file in python. Below I am attaching a photo of hom XML file looks like and I would like for each id (e.g. PZH01_MST_0690_00) to take the minimum trafficFlow, in this case it would be: 60. Can someone help me out? I guess people with more experience can do this fairly easy. Essentially, I want to convert this XML file to a CSV and have 2 columns (1 with the id and 2 the lowest trafficFlow). Any help would be much appreciated, thank you!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

-<SOAP:Envelope xmlns:SOAP="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">


-<SOAP:Body>


-<d2LogicalModel xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" modelBaseVersion="2" xmlns="http://datex2.eu/schema/2/2_0">


-<exchange>


-<supplierIdentification>

<country>nl</country>

<nationalIdentifier>NLNDW</nationalIdentifier>

</supplierIdentification>

</exchange>


-<payloadPublication lang="nl" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="MeasuredDataPublication">

<publicationTime>2019-10-31T11:12:42.005Z</publicationTime>


-<publicationCreator>

<country>nl</country>

<nationalIdentifier>NLNDW</nationalIdentifier>

</publicationCreator>

<measurementSiteTableReference targetClass="MeasurementSiteTable" version="1139" id="NDW01_MT"/>


-<headerInformation>

<confidentiality>noRestriction</confidentiality>

<informationStatus>real</informationStatus>

</headerInformation>


-<siteMeasurements xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

<measurementSiteReference targetClass="MeasurementSiteRecord" version="6" id="PZH01_MST_0690_00"/>

<measurementTimeDefault>2019-10-31T11:11:00Z</measurementTimeDefault>


-<measuredValue index="1">


-<measuredValue>


-<basicData xsi:type="TrafficFlow">


-<vehicleFlow>

<vehicleFlowRate>720</vehicleFlowRate>

</vehicleFlow>

</basicData>

</measuredValue>

</measuredValue>


-<measuredValue index="2">


-<measuredValue>


-<basicData xsi:type="TrafficFlow">


-<vehicleFlow>

<vehicleFlowRate>60</vehicleFlowRate>

</vehicleFlow>

</basicData>

</measuredValue>

</measuredValue>


-<measuredValue index="3">


-<measuredValue>


-<basicData xsi:type="TrafficFlow">


-<vehicleFlow>

<vehicleFlowRate>60</vehicleFlowRate>

</vehicleFlow>

</basicData>

</measuredValue>

</measuredValue>


-<measuredValue index="4">


-<measuredValue>


-<basicData xsi:type="TrafficFlow
```

Comment: Can you share the XML content here?

Comment: 1) Please show us what you have tried. What is the problem? 2) Please post XML as text, not as an image.

Comment: i tried to do add the xml content but the structure changes a lot

Comment: here is my best effort